# #include <graphic.h>

Tags: c++, graphic

how i use `#include <graphic.h>` in windows 7 and i use graphic function in visual studio c++ or borland c++  ???

tnx,but : Which library in Console Application mode work?

Comment: IIRC `graphic.h` is Borland-specific, not standard C++, which means that you can't use it with Visual Studio or GCC.

Comment: There have in fact been 8 major operating system releases since graphics.h still made sense.  Burn the book you're reading, it is hopelessly outdated.  Google "Borland museum" if you want to do this anyway.

Answer (score 3):

graphics.h is not a standard c++. It is only Borland specific. I recommend OpenGL library, SDL, or the similar graphic libraries.

Comment: Yes it is not a library. Thanks for adding.

Comment: tnx , but :    Which library in Console Application mode work?

Comment: If you want to do some graphics programming in C++ in Visual C++ which one would you add into the include file.

Comment: OpenGL is fine but how do I get that into my Visual C++ project, fast and painlessly. I am supposed to have some simple C++ graphics done by friday afternoon or monday at the latest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 or Borland Dev C++ for graphics.h.

For further detail, you can see this link: https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/visual/