# How can I compile code that uses graphics.h in DOSBOX?

Tags: c++, dosbox, bgi, borland-c++

i write a code and in this code i use graphics.h ,in borland c++ or visual I can't open and run it, now i want run this code ,and i have DOSBOX 0.72 , how open this code with DOSBOX?
my windows is 7 32bit

Comment: You should just use [WinBGIm](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/), a modern port of the original, and a modern compiler!

Answer (score 6):

I see you're [still trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574201/include-graphic-h) to write and compile code that uses legacy and unsupported libraries...

At least you've discovered now that you aren't going to be able to do this natively in Windows 7, and have installed a DOS emulator. Now, you'll need to find and download a compiler that will run in that environment.

Since `graphics.h` is a proprietary Borland library, I recommend you use one of their compilers. The company who now owns Borland hosts an [online museum](http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/antiquesoftware) of their vintage products that are free for download. **Grab a copy of [Turbo C 2.01](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20841) or [Turbo C++ 1.01](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21751), load it on your DOSBOX, and marvel at the little piece of computer history you've unearthed.**

Also, Turbo C 3.0 is available online from [here](http://www.brothersoft.com/turbo-c-download-182798.html), but I'm not sure this has been released to the public domain. I can't imagine anyone would really care, but legally and all, you're on your own.

But seriously, why not download [Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP) free from Microsoft and use a modern compiler instead? Sure you can't use `graphics.h`, but there have been a significant amount of developments made in computer graphics technology in the past 25+ years. A modern IDE will be *much* easier to use than the old Borland compilers, and the time you invest will actually be worth something.

Comment: +1, it's time to stop fighting and just use a modern compiler and NOT USE DOS.

Comment: No kidding. I still use Windows 2000/XP for some things, and I feel like a stubborn hold-out. Get off my lawn!

Comment: Actually, this has got me all thinking back to the days of DOS...  I never used Borland.  I fell in love with a compiler called `DJGPP` coupled with the RHIDE IDE.  It was an excellent compiler (http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/).

Comment: @Moo-Juice: The problem is mainly that the asker (and apparently others, too—see the related questions) is trying to use a proprietary header file included with Borland compilers (`graphics.h`). I doubt DJGPP will include that header, even if it's a superior compiler.

Comment: Oh, absolutely I wasn't suggesting it did.  Just reading "Turbo C++" and "DOS" took me back to the old days :)  "Time to debug this thing...  printf("1"); printf("2"); printf("3")...."

Answer (score 0):

May be download and install borland c++ 3.11 compiler and use graphic.h library (i'm use it 4 years ago).
I think that this compiler isn't ran in Win 7, but may be try. 
You can use Virtual Box, with installing Win XP (borland c++ 3.1 100% work in WinXP).

Comment: He says he already has [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). Why do you recommend Virtual Box instead? And why in the *world* were you writing 16-bit DOS applications with this compiler only 4 years ago?

Comment: I was writing 16-bit DOS applications with this compiler in the university in practical training. Our lecturer supposed that writing in 3.1 will give us good understanding command syntax of C++

Comment: I recommend install Virtual Box because he can use Win XP and don't have problem with running dos program in Win 7.

Comment: @Moo-Juice why? In my opinion, in university we were writing in borland c++ because 3.1 is freeware and don't necessary to pay for usage, such as visual studio

Comment: There's zero benefit in running Windows XP in Virtual Box and then DOS programs on top of that. Modern operating systems (including Windows) only have a DOS compatibility layer—it's not real DOS. Most things will work properly there, but why not use the real thing if you've got it? Plus, using Windows XP would require him to acquire a *license* for Windows XP, whereas there are versions of DOS available for free.

Comment: @G-71, when was this, exactly?

Comment: Visual Studio Express is free—see the link provided in my answer. There are plenty of other compilers that are also released for free. Using nearly 20 year old software is *not* teaching you anything relevant or useful. If I were you, I'd demand a refund on that education. That's like writing Win16 applications and learning about long pointers. Useless, unless you have a time machine.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution of running turbo C++ 3.0 in windows 7 is just disable graphics driver of your computer from device manager and use like windows Xp.

It will run turbo c++ in full screen as well as run graphics program in windows 7