# A graphics program does not run in Borland C++. What can I do?

Tags: c++, bgi, borland-c++

When I run a simple graphics program in Borland C++, it throws the error "BGI graphics not supported under Windows".

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {

    int gd = DETECT, gm;

    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

    circle(100, 100, 50);

    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: i use borland c++ software,i can't run graphics program in borland c++

Comment: 2013! Why would you want to do that at all? Compiling an old game someone wrote 20+ years ago?

Comment: @Dmitry Ledentsov: No, because [curricula and text books are](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-GCC-and-Clang-over-Turbo-C/answer/Paulina-Jonu%C5%A1ait%C4%97) [not being updated](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra). ***Everything is frozen in time.*** Another example is *[Wren & Martin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645)*.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run DOS, you might have some luck investigating [WinBGI](http://winbgim.codecutter.org), but the project looks like it's gone to seed. Ultimately BGI is an obsolete and unsupported technology.

If you're just having a bit of a play, perhaps the HTML Canvas element would be a plausible alternative. *[HTML Canvas Graphics](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)* has a few demos you can modify on the fly.

See also this similar question: *[How can I compile code that uses graphics.h in DOSBOX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646170/how-can-i-compile-code-that-uses-graphics-h-in-dosbox)*

Comment: can't run in DOS , WinBGI not supported in WINDOWS 64bit and i have windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

Go to menu *Options* → *Linker* → *Libraries*

Then select the graphics library.

Comment: In what context? Borland C++? Turbo C++? What version? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Run your program under MS-DOS or switch to another graphics library.

(BTW the last time I had something to do with BGI was in the 90s...)

Comment: which another graphics library and which location set library ?

Comment: Depends on your system. And do you want to make a console application? If so, SDL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) could be what you are looking for.

Comment: i can't get perfect solution, give me perfect solution run graphics program in borland c++

Answer (score -1):

Well, one thing you can do is try the Turbo C++ compiler. Borland is new and doesn't support BGI graphics. I had the same problem and it is much better to use Turbo C++ (not the 4.5 version). Last year I had to use them and Borland didn't support them. I loved the Borland compiler.

TIP: if you are not learning BGI graphics for some special reason, I would suggest you to use other graphic libraries in other compilers (like [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks)) which support the new C++ standards.